# Why am I getting 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."' error when trying to invoke google map in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-maps, cllocationmanager, api-key

[image: Dashboard og my Google cloud platform]I am getting error everytime when invoking google map in my iOS app as follows:

```
load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x283671e90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <27BC82BB-492A-4C55-B351-35C2E91B2607>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <27BC82BB-492A-4C55-B351-35C2E91B2607>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1} [-1004]
```

I tried to add ATS keys,but I am getting 
`Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Request timed out.`" error in my app. I have tried in different networks but still the same issue. Any idea why such issue occurs?

I have downloaded the basic sample codes from git and tried my API key with it. I have removed the iOS bundle identifier restrictions so that it can be used in demo app.I also added the demo bundle identifier to my api key to check. None works, I cannot see maps in my screen.
Please note I am using 1 year trial API key by google to perform the tests.

The call from code to show maps is as follows:

In `viewDidLoad` :-

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self._locationManager =locationManager;
self._locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self._locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self._locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self._locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self._locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self._locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:self._locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude zoom:15];
self.mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024,724) camera:camera];
self.mapView_.delegate=self;
self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
self.mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
self.mapView_.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;

TestTileLayer *titleLayer = [[TestTileLayer alloc] init];
self.testTileLayer = titleLayer;
self.testTileLayer.map = self.mapView_;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView_] ;
[self showPinFromLocation];
```

and then in `showPinFromLocation` :-

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = _currentLocation;
NSString *api = [NSString stringWithFormat:kMapAPIForLocation, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, apiKey];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:api];

__block PMIiSMSPlace *placeMark = nil;

GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
self.marker3 = marker;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {

DLog(@"Response Code = %ld", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);

if(error){
    [m_objGlobal.g_objExceptionHandler sendErrorCode:m_objGlobalData.g_strSelectedJourneyPlanNumber withVisitNumber:m_objGlobalData. g_strSelectedVisitNumber withExceptionReason:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to fetch address from google map error desc = %@", error.description] withErrorCode:error.code];
    DLog(@"Map Error = %@", error.userInfo);
}

if(data){

        placeMark = [self parseData:data];

        self.currentPlace = placeMark;
        self.marker3.position=_currentLocation;
        self.marker3.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        self.marker3.title=placeMark.formatted_address;
        self.marker3.snippet=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f,%.6f",self.marker3.position.latitude,self.marker3.position.longitude ];
        self.marker3.map = self.mapView_;
        [self.marker3 setDraggable:YES];

        placeMark = nil;
    }else{
        placeMark = [[PMIiSMSPlace alloc] init];

        self.currentPlace = placeMark;
        self.marker3.position=self->_currentLocation;
        self.marker3.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        self.marker3.title=placeMark.formatted_address;
        self.marker3.snippet=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f,%.6f",self.marker3.position.latitude,self.marker3.position.longitude ];

        self.marker3.map = self.mapView_;
        [self.marker3 setDraggable:YES];

        placeMark = nil;

    }

 }] resume];

 }
```

I expect the data to be fetched successfully and the completion handler to enter the data block. But the call always enters the error block now. Its not entering the data block at all.

Comment: add NSTransport security

Comment: I added 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' and 'Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content'. No changes in error. Same "Could not connect to the server."

Comment: have added key in AppDelegate ? too ?

Comment: From the error message "the request timed out", it looks like you just don't have an active Internet connection? Or issue is with your device  Or May be your Key for GMS is valid and you entered correctly but your Application in google console is not enabled yet

Comment: I have added the key in appdelegate. Could you please detail about the application in google console not being enabled yet?

Comment: when you create a project in google console for googleMaps  you set your application bundle id too after settings bundle id you get googlemaps api key that you have added in appDelegate  after getting the key there is a switch  in project settings of google console to enable project. you might have not enabled that one

Comment: In the dashboard page, there is button called 'enable api & services'. The button tap leads to API library page. but the 'Maps sdk for iOS' and 'Geocoding API' are already added to the project and are enabled. I do not find any project enablement button.

Comment: can you please attach a screen shot of  google console for Maps SDK for IOS

Comment: here is a person facing same issue and he solved it by just replacing google server key 
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary/issues/17

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the post. Will try out the suggestion as in the link. Thanks a lot.